# Php Google plus domain api delete post and comment

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, google-plus-domains

I am working in a project where i am showing Google plus user posts using php Google Plus Api Sdk. 
I have a problem.
How to insert post and comments?
How to delete post and comments?

Please Help me.

Thank you

Comment: Yes there is not avaliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google+ != Google plus domains**

You have tagged your question both Google+ and Google+ domains which are two very different things.

- Google+ is a social meda website found [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/).
- Google+ domains is a company controlled website for [gSuite](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_ie/features/) customers.

**Google+ API** for the socalmedia site.

The Google+ api is read only, you can only get data.  There is no insert or delete functionality.   You can only read what a user has put on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/)

Documentation [Activities about.](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities)

> An activity is a note that a user posts to their stream. Activity methods enable your application to list a collection of activities, **get** an activity and **search** through activities.

**Google Domains API**

> With the Google+ Domains API, G Suite customers and ISVs can build custom Google+ functionality and services for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home. Organizations can develop tools to interact with Google+ features such as posts, comments, and circles. These tools let your users share information, reinforce communications, and grow productivity within your organization.

This allows for Select, insert update and delete of posts to the domains page.

Comment: Ok you mean i need to register with G suit then i will able to insert, update and delete.

Comment: i registered with g suit and all working but i didn't find api for delete activity , like activity, delete comment and like.
I see in zoho social site they delete activity but there is no documentation in google

Comment: There isn't a public one some sites have a special agreement with Google that allows them different accounts.